# HeadlessUI switch Tabs with Navbar

Tags: reactjs, next.js, state, react-state, headless-ui

i have a Tabs-Section ([headlessui](https://headlessui.dev/react/tabs)) and in my Navbar has Links/Buttons for each Tab. My Problem is now that i don't know how i controll the Tabs with the buttons/links in the Navbar. And yes the Tabs are also controlled by the Tab.List.

The Page is structured like this:

```
<app>
  <IndexPage(File)>
    <LayoutComponent> // in this component is the navbar-component
       {content}
       <SectionComponent>
         <Tabs.Group>
            ...
         </Tabs.Group>
       </SectionComponent>
       {content}
    <LayoutComponent> 
  </IndexPage>
</app>
```

And i tried to handle the TabIndex with react-state ([like this](https://headlessui.dev/react/tabs#specifying-the-default-tab)) but i don't know how to forward a state through so many components.
My second try was with URL-Querys, but this have many bugs, and it worked not really good.
Is there a way to solve my Problem?

ps: my project is with nextjs

Answer (score 0):

I'm now using the React Context API to build a DataProvider and it works perfectly